# What's the story (tv series? film? novel?) where two people have a shoot-out while each stands in a tub?

Tags: story-identification

After a battle (I think), a fighter gambles her life by taking part in a shoot-out with a stranger. 
The shooters are standing in wash tubs, because that makes it easier for the organisers of the shootout to pick the body up and carry it away. The body dissolves when shot.
The crowd of onlookers bet on who will survive. The winner walks away with their life and some of the money.

The character we know kills her opponent, takes her money, and heads for a bar. She meets up with an old friend (rival, comrade in arms) who has also played the "tub game" and won...

I read/saw this in 2016 or 2017.

Comment: What about this is fantasy or sci-fi?

Comment: I'm not sure how, if this only was a year or so ago, you can't remember if this was a book you read or something you saw on TV.

Comment: Mr Lister - because I'm a visual reader, so remembering a scene from a book is like remembering a scene from film/tv. And I binge-watch and binge-read, so stories can get mushed together in my memory.

Comment: "The body dissolves when shot." -- this sounds like SF to me.

Comment: In what way does the body dissolve? Do you mean that it turns into liquid (hence the tubs)?

Comment: Yes, the body dissolves instantly into liquid when hit.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a scene from True Blood to me, first episode of the last season (7), when Pam is looking for Eric.  It's not a shoot out though, it's Russian Roulette.

[Here's the scene on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjP5GwzOo4w)

Comment: Oh, thank you, Bekah! That's it!